# GCS HTTP2_STREAM_ERROR - net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-storage

We run some websites that are mapped directly to GCS so website.com has a bucket called website.com and it has all the html pages and static files in it.

Just yesterday we suddenly had a page with significant number of .svg image files (+/- 50 but all very small < 2kb). And also a bunch (lets say 10-15) .png images.

And from those all the .svg files and only 2 of the .png files are failing to load with error:
net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200.

It works FINE on Firefox and MS Edge browser. ONLY on Chrome it fails.

I have searched and most issues were to do with bad headers or nginx settings but this is directly to GCS buckets so we do not control any of that.

I ran network log via Chrome:

```
t= 5285 [st=  700]       -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t= 5286 [st=  701]        HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_INFO  [dt=0]
t= 5286 [st=  701]        HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_DATA  [dt=0]
t= 5286 [st=  701]       +NETWORK_DELEGATE_HEADERS_RECEIVED  [dt=12]
t= 5289 [st=  704]          HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                            --> delta = -543
                            --> stream_id = 41
                            --> window_size = 6290913
t= 5298 [st=  713]       -NETWORK_DELEGATE_HEADERS_RECEIVED
t= 5298 [st=  713]     -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
t= 5298 [st=  713]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_RESPONSE_STARTED  [dt=0]
t= 5298 [st=  713]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t= 5298 [st=  713]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                          --> delta = 543
                          --> stream_id = 41
                          --> window_size = 6291456
t= 5298 [st=  713]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY
t= 5298 [st=  713]      URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                        --> byte_count = 543
t= 5298 [st=  713]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=60021]
t=65319 [st=60734]        HTTP2_STREAM_ERROR
                          --> description = "Server reset stream."
                          --> net_error = "ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
                          --> stream_id = 41
t=65319 [st=60734]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY
                        --> net_error = -337 (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=65319 [st=60734]      FAILED
                        --> net_error = -337 (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=65347 [st=60762] -CORS_REQUEST
t=65347 [st=60762] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                    --> net_error = -337 (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
```

(there's more but I figured this was the part that matters; if not I can provide whole log).

Any help to solve this mystery would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example URL?

Comment: sure; https://goagencyscale.com/commercial/sales 
Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images stored in Cloud Storage are fine and are not the source of the Chrome error. The problem is caused by your JavaScript. There is another issue in that your page performs cross-site actions that Chrome is blocking. The two issues might be related.

Ask the developer that wrote the code to debug and correct this problem.

In summary, this is not a Chrome bug. The issue might be caused by Chrome taking action against your page's behavior. The end result is you must fix your application. The same problem exists in Edge 102.

**[UPDATE]**

The actual problem is the HTTP header **x-goog-meta-link**. The size of that header (metadata) is 7,461 bytes. The combined HTTP headers exceeded 8 KB which is the cause of the problem.

Comment: nope that is not it.. weirdest stuff though:
https://goagencyscale.com/commercial/salestest3.html 
Exact same page.. copied the html source and reuploaded it manually. And works just fine.

Comment: @stevesrs - They are not the same files. However, I noticed something different between the two versions. The HTTP headers are different. The problem one has a huge **x-goog-meta-link** which is 7,461 bytes long. That header is too big. The total HTTP headers exceed 8KB. Go to the Google Cloud Console. Find the **sales** object. Delete that header and try again. Do a hard page refresh in Chrome to reload the page. What tool did you use to upload the files that created that header?

Comment: I think that is it! I actually tried and tested removing it yesterday as well but didn't work but I think I didn't wait long enough to test it. I'm sure GCS has some delay in propagating that file change. Thank you!

(btw we create that header ourselves; its for http2 push files HUGE speed gain but clearly we need to limit it for ridiculously large pages with SO many images)