# Why would an http1.1 request to a golang web server result in ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (Server reset stream)?

Tags: google-chrome, go, http, webserver

I have a simple golang web server that serves gzipped files. 95% of the time, a page will load just fine, but every so often, I will get the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 error. When I record the requests using chrome's network logging tool, I can see that the reason for this protocol error is "Server reset stream.", but the golang web server just proceeds as normal when that error happens, no interruptions, no write errors, etc. Also, why is this an http2 protocol error? Chrome network request does show h2 for the protocol, but the golang server reports http1.1 as the request's protocol.

I've seen a ton of potential reasons in other threads about why this might be happening, but none of them appear to have relevance in my situation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611187/gcs-http2-stream-error-neterr-http2-protocol-error-200) was the closest thing to my situation I could find.

Things I thought it might have been based on those other threads where people had their problems fixed:

- gzip writer was not closed before request was returned
- not enough disk space and/or insufficient cpu resources
- missing content length header

I checked each of those in my code and configuration, and adjusting/fixing those points did nothing.

The worst part about it is that it is inconsistent. Like I mentioned, it almost always loads just fine, but if I repeatedly load pages over and over again and navigate between pages on my site, eventually, I will come across this error.

Other things to note:

- potentially has something to do with caching, since I can most consistently reproduce this issue when I load a page for the first time that day (not always, but definitely happens more often on the first page load(s) of the day.)
- almost every single time this happens, the chrome request network tool shows that the request was stalled for a bit and then the download time is always 5.7s. The queued, stalled, etc are always variable, but the download time is consistently 5.7s. Not sure if that is any indication of something.
- maybe has something to do with Google Cloud Storage since that is what is being gzipped (request is made for a file, file is read from GCS into bytes, bytes are compressed, server writes compressed bytes to client), but I have also seen this with a web server that simlpy reads from a mounted nfs, so not sure about GCS being an issue

If you have some ideas of what might be causing this inconsistent/intermittent error, please let me know. Even better, if you have a solid method for debugging golang http web server errors like this, I'd love to hear it!

**UPDATES:**

- Some more info on this bit: `Also, why is this an http2 protocol error? Chrome network request does show h2 for the protocol, but the golang server reports http1.1 as the request's protocol`: I just discovered that the reason even Chrome's http/2 requests are hitting the go web server as http1.1 requests is due to my kubernetes load balancer configuration. The protocol was set to HTTP, so I've just switched it to HTTP/2, and changed the go web server from `http.ListenAndServe` to use `http.ListenAndServeTLS`. Now I can see requests are consistently coming in as http/2.
- Even after switching to http/2 only, still getting this error